# Select box on user account page

Tags: users

I would like to add a select box dropdown (User A, User B) on the user account creation page that would redisplay the page with different fields based on the  selection.

#### User A

- Username
- E-mail Address
- Account Number

#### User B

- Username
- E-mail address
- Dealer Number

User A will have the *User A* role; user B will have the *User B* role.

I'm not a coder and it seems really hard to accomplish this.

Any suggestions would be appreciate.